# DFA that accepts strings ending with an even number of 1 in the last three characters ("000","110","101","011")

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I need to design a binary DFA to accept strings where the last three characters read are either "000", "110", "101" or "011". 
My brutal solution is: [image]

---

I need help either reducing this one or with a simpler solution. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't $000$ be final? It has an even (zero) number of $1$'s in the last three characters.

Comment: Good point, it should totally be

Comment: Your "brutal solution" is quite natural. It builds a so-called [De Bruijn graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction) which keeps the last three symbols from the input.

Answer (score 2):

There are some merging of states that you could make, but the minimal automaton is still quite big, I think:

- states with the same number of characters are not equivalent, because either one is final and not the other, or you could read one or two more letters to get into a final state for one and not the other.
- the state $S$ cannot be equivalent to another state, because it is the only one at distance $3$ of any final state;
- for a similar reason, the states $0$ and $1$ cannot be equivalent to any other;
- a 2-characters state $ab$ can only be equivalent to a 3-characters $cde$ if $ab = de$ and $cde$ is not final. One can note that since the following pairs are non-final states with the same exiting transitions, they are equivalent:

  - $00$ is equivalent to $100$;
  - $01$ is equivalent to $001$;
  - $10$ is equivalent to $010$;
  - $11$ is equivalent to $111$.

You'd get a $11$ states automaton.